# I am trying to create an app with mysql android connection. but the app abruptly halts

Tags: android, networkonmainthread

I am trying to create an app with mysql android connection. but the app abruptly halts. I don't understand what is causing the problem. I have asked about the same problem in my previous questions. Pls help. I am desperate. It's for my academic project

the error is

```
04-28 15:43:29.918: D/dalvikvm(8036): Late-enabling CheckJNI
04-28 15:43:30.278: D/dalvikvm(8036): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 78K, 12% free 9560K/10759K, paused 33ms, total 33ms
04-28 15:43:30.288: I/dalvikvm-heap(8036): Grow heap (frag case) to 10.705MB for 437672-byte allocation
04-28 15:43:30.358: D/dalvikvm(8036): GC_CONCURRENT freed <1K, 11% free 9986K/11207K, paused 13ms+7ms, total 70ms
04-28 15:43:30.358: D/dalvikvm(8036): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 55ms
04-28 15:43:30.449: D/dalvikvm(8036): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 2K, 11% free 10211K/11463K, paused 56ms, total 57ms
04-28 15:43:30.649: D/libEGL(8036): loaded /system/lib/egl/libEGL_mali.so
04-28 15:43:30.759: D/libEGL(8036): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_mali.so
04-28 15:43:30.789: D/libEGL(8036): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv2_mali.so
04-28 15:43:30.879: D/OpenGLRenderer(8036): Enabling debug mode 0
04-28 15:43:32.130: D/dalvikvm(8036): GC_CONCURRENT freed 11K, 9% free 10906K/11975K, paused 4ms+6ms, total 56ms
04-28 15:43:32.130: D/dalvikvm(8036): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 31ms
04-28 15:43:32.200: D/dalvikvm(8036): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed <1K, 10% free 11335K/12487K, paused 47ms, total 47ms
04-28 15:43:32.290: D/dalvikvm(8036): GC_CONCURRENT freed 3K, 8% free 11992K/12999K, paused 3ms+13ms, total 71ms
04-28 15:43:32.681: E/SpannableStringBuilder(8036): SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length
04-28 15:43:32.681: E/SpannableStringBuilder(8036): SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length
04-28 15:43:34.422: E/SpannableStringBuilder(8036): SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length
04-28 15:43:34.422: E/SpannableStringBuilder(8036): SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length
04-28 15:43:35.994: D/ProgressBar(8036): setProgress = 0
04-28 15:43:35.994: D/ProgressBar(8036): setProgress = 0, fromUser = false
04-28 15:43:35.994: D/ProgressBar(8036): mProgress = 0mIndeterminate = false, mMin = 0, mMax = 10000
04-28 15:43:36.124: W/ResourceType(8036): Failure getting entry for 0x010802c8 (t=7 e=712) in package 0 (error -75)
04-28 15:43:36.474: D/AndroidRuntime(8036): Shutting down VM
04-28 15:43:36.474: W/dalvikvm(8036): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41a162a0)
04-28 15:43:36.534: E/AndroidRuntime(8036): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-28 15:43:36.534: E/AndroidRuntime(8036): android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
04-28 15:43:36.534: E/AndroidRuntime(8036):     at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1118)
04-28 15:43:36.534: E/AndroidRuntime(8036):     at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:385)
04-28 15:43:36.534: E/AndroidRuntime(8036):     at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:236)
04-28 15:43:36.534: E/AndroidRuntime(8036):     at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:214)
04-28 15:43:36.534: E/AndroidRuntime(8036):     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:137)
04-28 15:43:36.534: E/AndroidRuntime(8036):     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:164)
04-28 15:43:36.534: E/AndroidRuntime(8036):     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:119)
04-28 15:43:36.534: E/AndroidRuntime(8036):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:360)
04-28 15:43:36.534: E/AndroidRuntime(8036):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:555)
04-28 15:43:36.534: E/AndroidRuntime(8036):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:487)
04-28 15:43:36.534: E/AndroidRuntime(8036):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:465)
04-28 15:43:36.534: E/AndroidRuntime(8036):     at com.mahavega.qcdemo.JSONParser.makeHttpRequest(JSONParser.java:62)
04-28 15:43:36.534: E/AndroidRuntime(8036):     at com.mahavega.qcdemo.MainActivity$GetEventDetails$1.run(MainActivity.java:198)
04-28 15:43:36.534: E/AndroidRuntime(8036):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
04-28 15:43:36.534: E/AndroidRuntime(8036):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
04-28 15:43:36.534: E/AndroidRuntime(8036):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
04-28 15:43:36.534: E/AndroidRuntime(8036):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4856)
04-28 15:43:36.534: E/AndroidRuntime(8036):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-28 15:43:36.534: E/AndroidRuntime(8036):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
04-28 15:43:36.534: E/AndroidRuntime(8036):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1007)
04-28 15:43:36.534: E/AndroidRuntime(8036):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:774)
04-28 15:43:36.534: E/AndroidRuntime(8036):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: please provide Source Code.

Comment: Which android release do you use on your emulator and project?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16259430/connecting-android-to-mysql-database-application-ends

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you are trying to make network connections on the "main" thread which android doesn't allows.
Try using AsyncTask.

Answer (score 1):

I think I found it. Probably your android version is android 4.0 and above, you are trying to carry out a network operation on your main thread. But android 4.0 and above does not allow this operation because you are not allowed to interrupt main thread of application with a network operation. You should do your network operation in an `AsyncTask`.  Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

From your log it seems that you are trying to do slow network operation on main thread because this can block UI and application will not respond.

try to do whatever stuff you are doing in background using `doInBackground()`

Answer (score 0):

Although it's for an academic project, you never should access a remote sql database from a client application. This is unsafe, especially in java/android.

Create a nice REST webservice layer between your app and your remote database. so you can sanitize user input on the server side, because all user input is per definition evil :)

**But**, as I intepret the logcat you are already using a webservice. the exception is really clear on the error: NetworkOnMainThreadException